# Intersection of subspace of cyclical rotations with orthant

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, geometric-probability

In an $N$-dimensional real Euclidian space, let an orthant be specified by a vector
$\underline{x}_0 = \{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_N\}$ where the components $x_k$ are binary in  the sense that   $x_k = \pm 1$.

Now let $\underline{x}_j$ be cyclical rotations of  that vector $\underline{x}_0$, such that the components are $x_{k+j}$ where the indices are understood modulo $N$.  Span a space of vectors  $V = {\rm span} \{ \underline{x}_1, \underline{x}_2, \dots, \underline{x}_d \} $. What is the minimum number of $d$ such that $V$ intersects the original orthant indicated by $\underline{x}_0$?

This question can either be understood when notion of the original $\underline{x}_0$ is available, or in an average sense over randomly picked $\underline{x}_0$ where $N$ is large. In the latter case, it is reasonable to make the vector $\underline{x}_0$ almost mean-free, i.e. by imposing $|\sum_{k=1}^N x_k| \le 1$. Also, conditions on $N$ may be useful, i.e. demanding that $N$ is prime.

Background 1:
If the vectors $ \{ \underline{x}_1, \underline{x}_2, \dots, \underline{x}_d \} $ were randomly picked and in general position, it is known that, as $N$ turns large, the probability of the span intersecting any particular orthant approaches 1 as $d \ge 0.50 N$ (Thomas Cover, Geometrical and Statistical Properties of Systems of Linear Threshold Devices, 1964). In the present cyclical case, although the vectors could still be assumed in general position, the probability of the span intersecting the original orthant is, by large scale simulations, known to approach 1 as $d \ge 0.59 N$, i.e. the subspace dimensionality $d$ must be ca. 18 % larger.  (M. Schröder, W. Kinzel and I. Kanter: Training a perceptron by a bit sequence: storage capacity, J. Phys. A 29 7965-7972, 1996). To my knowledge, there is no explanation for this published.

Background 2: One could demand a stronger condition, namely that $\underline{x}_0 = \sum_{j=1}^d w_j \underline{x}_j$ holds, with freely chosen $w_j$. However, it can be shown by Discrete Fourier Transformation that this condition can be met only in very special cases, and when $N$ is prime and  $\underline{x}_0$ is almost mean-free, it is impossible to achieve.

Comment: If you take $\underline x_0=(-1,1,1,1,\dots,1)$, then you need almost all cyclic shifts, otherwise the first two coordinates of any vector in the space will be equal.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov True, this is one of the extreme cases. I'm looking for a systematic approach.